# Incorrect key file for table MYSQL

Tags: mysql

When i want to GROUP BY a query i get this error message:

```
Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_623d_0.MYI'; try to repair it
```

It is an InnoDB table with 3.000.000 records and 4,3 GiB large.

When I run

```
repair table mytablename
```

I get this message:

```
The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair
```

Optimize won't work. What to do?

Comment: This may not a repair problem but a space problem when creating the temporary file. Try to use `LIMIT` by the way and see what happens. See link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908228/incorrect-key-file-with-mysql)

Comment: The incorrect key file seems to be a MyISAM index, judging by the name, not an InnoDB one.

Comment: @vmai well, phpmyadmin said it is InnoDB but i can remember that i created a MyISAM table so it could be right. and regarding to the filename it is indeed. Maybe a bug in PhpMyAdmin

Comment: @edper, i tried limit 100 and limit 10, still the same message: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_623d_0.MYI'; try to repair it

Comment: @esper i removed the GROUP BY because the link told it could help but even without the group by and with limit 10 it is still nog working.

Comment: To get the result of a GROUP BY clause there's often a temporary table needed, see [GROUP BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-optimization.html). Probably MySQL uses the MyISAM storage engine for this task. So maybe @Edper is poking in the right direction: how much disk space do you have on /tmp?

Comment: @vmai /dev/root        site: 20G, used: 16G, avail: 2.7G, use%:  86%

Comment: @vmai and when i try to run the query the diskspace slowly increases to 100%. When it reaches the 100% it displays the error message try to repair it :) problem found.

Comment: is it possible to extend the size of /dev/root or do i have to change the folder for temp tables in mysql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was not that the table was corrupt. When you do a group by, mysql creates a temporary table. Because the table is so large, the temporary table takes more than 10gb of diskspace. The error message appears when the disk got 100% full.

I used the commando to check the diskspace:

```
df -h /dev/root
```

So in the MySQL config (my.ini) I changed the location (tmpdir) where the temporary tables are stored to a partition with enough free diskspace.

now the query runs succesfull