# MySQL table becoming corrupted daily

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, myisam, corrupt

In our system we have a table which over the night is under constant attack (we do many imports at night) 
Because we were getting fewer records than usual we put some sneaks in the imports code and it raised up that in many update statements the"Incorrect key file for table './xxx/zzz.MYI'; try to repair it". error appears.

I can repair it every day, but the next morning the errors appear again.

How can I find out which is the cause?
May it be happening because there's too many inserts/updates at the same time?
Will switching to innoDB solve the problem?
Anybody knows anything abut it?

Also I collect the errors in the php which do the imports somehow the table don't get lebeled as crashed and keeps working.

It's a myisam table whit about 500.000 rows and the imports are 12  XML feeds(of about 10MB each) full of car ads that are inserted/updated to the table in question.

Could it be for the table size?

thank you!

Comment: "Will switching to InnoDB solve the problem?" I assume you are then working with MyISAM tables, am I correct?

Comment: As for the imports... What are you importing? Are you importing text files? Are you performing massive inserts? Are you uploding files and storing them as `BLOB`s? Please add a little more detail to your question

Comment: Yes, it's a myIsam table

Comment: Is your table *really* big? MyISAM locks the full table when performing DMLs

Comment: well we read some(12) XML feeds(of about 10MB each) full of car ads that are inserted/updated to the table in question

Comment: It's about 500000 rows is it too much?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the volume of inserts... but, of course, if you are running out of disk space or you are performing many concurrent writes, that could be an issue...

Comment: Are you running out of disk space?

Comment: what do you think about switching to innoDB? It blocks at row level, I think it should be better.

Comment: about 60GB of disk and 1GB in /tmp I think it's enough, isn't it?

Comment: Is the corrupt .MYI file located in /tmp? If yes, then you should watch the free space in /tmp while importing, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/25823106/3501730

Comment: Of course migrate to InnoDB if you care about your data.

Comment: Can the corruption be caused by hard disk bad blocks?