# MySQL VIEW Incorrect key file for table try to repair it

Tags: mysql, view

I have a `FooBar` view like:

```
CREATE VIEW `FooBar` AS 
SELECT * FROM `Foo`.`Bar`
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM `Foo1`.`Bar`
```

When I `SELECT * FROM FooBar` I get:

> Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_1234_5.MYI'; try to repair it

When I run the select statements like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Foo`.`Bar`
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM `Foo1`.`Bar`
```

Everything goes well. The problem is clearly with my FooBar view.

When I `REPAIR TABLE FooBar` I get

> 'WhiskerDatabase.VisualDiscrimSuperimposed_Results' is not BASE TABLE
>
> Corrupt

I tried to `DROP VIEW FooBar`and re`CREATE VIEW FooBar`... but the problems persists.

And I can't locate the sql_1234_5.MYI file in `/var/lib/mysql/MyDB/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908228/incorrect-key-file-with-mysql). MySQL build a temporary file. The temporary file is too big to fit in memory.

Adjusting the system memory or using a `LIMIT` clause could help solve the problem.

I solve my problem by creating a procedure that create a table instead of a view. Such as:

```
DROP TABLE `FooBar` IF EXISTS;
CREATE TABLE `FooBar` AS SELECT * FROM `Foo`.`Bar`;
INSERT INTO `FooBar` SELECT * FROM `Foo1`.`Bar`;
```